# How do you remove the Notes and Attachments icons from a GRID

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to remove the files and Notes icons from the Grid on the My Documents(SP402000) page in the portal. I want to save data in the notes that the customers should not be able to see.

[image: SP402000customization]

[image: sp402000screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to remove the files & notes are the same for any Acumatica screen.  Set the two properties to False, in the grid properties.
If you remove it in the customer portal screen, the user can still see the notes and files, in the AR invoice/entry screen (regular ERP).
[image]